# Setting values in LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a project where i need to load results from one entity
select results and than with those results to load another 2 entities and select from them data wich will be return later.

is it possiable to build LINQ Query from 3 repositories
?
please give me some code examples or point me to links...i cannot find how

this is just a doodle of something that i ask if it possiable:

```
  ARepository rep = new AReository();
    BRepository rep = new BReository();
      var Q1= rep.GetAllView1()
                      .Select(o=>new {
                        X=o.data.aaa,
                        Y=o.data.bbb,
    ....
      var Q2= rep.GetAllView2()
                        .Where(x => x.bata.ss == X

      var Q3= rep.GetAllView3()
                        .Where(x => x.cata.ff== Y
```

Comment: Have you tried something from your end? If yes, then what error you are getting? We would be interested in knowing what is the exact problem that you are facing.

Comment: What are `AReository` and `BReository`? Your code won't compile if they are both named `rep`. Do you have two databases?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use navigation properties for this to be in any way efficient.  What you show is possible, but you are very likely to end up getting all the entities back when you do not need them.  It looks from your example that you have three entities:

### View1

- aaa
- bbb

### View2

- ss -> foreign key relationship to View1.aaa

### View3

- ff -> foreign key relationship to View1.bbb

The easiest is to have these keys defined in the database but you can define them in the entity framework designer.  Once you have the relationships modelled, it makes things really easy...

So the View1 entitiy could look like this:

```
public class View1
{
    public ICollection<View2> View2s { get; set; }

    public ICollection<View3> View3s { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have such an entity the following code would work:

```
rep
    .GetAllView1()
    .Where(o => o.View2s != null && 
           o.View2s.Count() > 0 && 
           o.View3s != null && 
           o.View3s.Count() > 0)
```

By this point you have a collection of View1 objects, all with 2 properties with their associated View2 and View3 entities.

Comment: I agree that Navigation Properties are always the best thing, but in this case I don't think they are possible - I believe that the question is about 3 different Entity contexts (possibly three different databases?)

Comment: Ah, I assumed they were using something like the repository pattern with the same context - my bad - sorry!  Yes, if they are different contexts then you have little choice but to execute a query against one, take the result and execute a second query against another.

Comment: user1039947 - this is excatly my question. but how can i retrun all the counts from each view2 and view3....? i need something like count(o.View2.id == o.View1.id)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not clear on what you mean exactly - do you want to know how many View2 entities you have for each View1?  If so - rep.GetAllView1().Where(o => o.View2s != null && o.View2s.Count() > 0).Select(o => new { count =  o.View2s.Count, id = o.id}) would give you collection of anonymous objects each with a count and the ID of the entity

Comment: imagen that the first entity with 3 details only - id number , car number and date. you have another 2 entities 'cars entity' and 'users entity'. your client side gives you date - you need to turn to the first entity take out the id and the car number and with those details you need to turn to the 'car entity' and return how many resutls with this car number. and than to call to the 'users entity' and count how many results with this id number

Comment: Firstly, can I kindly suggest you update your question as it is really unclear and I don't think comments like this are the best way to get to the information.  Secondly, it sounds like you need to define navigation properties between your 'car entity' and 'user entity'.  Are you wanting to know how many users you have for each "car number"?  That would require a grouping.